# Complete gradient shrinking Ricci soliton with nonnegative Ricci curvature?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Besides the product of a positive Einstein manifold with the Euclidean Gaussian shrinker, does there exist other complete (nonconpact) gradient shrinking Ricci soliton with nonnegative Ricci curvature?

Comment: Probably this is only known in dimension 3: see Theorem 1.1 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.5579v3.pdf. Can you give some explanation as to why you're interested in solitons with (in particular) non-negative Ricci curvature?

Comment: A interesting problem is the classification for shrinking Ricci solitons. There are examples of gradient shrinking Ricci soliton with undefinite Ricci curvature. So I want to get to some insight from different kinds of examples.

Comment: By Ni's result, $Ric\geq 0$ implies that $R>c$ for some positive constant. I'm not quite sure but it seems that all known examples have $R\to 0$.

Comment: @Yiyan Could you please give me some references about shrinking (or steady) Ricci soliton with undefinite Ricci curvature? I am looking for an example.